Sign preserving property for continuous functions of several variables
It is well-known that for continuous real functions, if $f(a)>0$ for some $a$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ such the function $f$ restricted to $U$ is positive. What if we have a continuous function of several variables? What is the best that we can say? How about more general spaces?

The identical proof should work just as well. Have you looked at it?
